# Import translation file without using the salesforce interface

Tags: apex, customlabel, translation, unlocked-package, translation-workbench

I have a question after generating the package of my salesforce application.

In the organization that develops my app, use the translation system, even generate my .xlf file to have the tags you used translated. In this organization I import the file from the translation system section, however when generating the unlocked package the file is ignored, I have not even been able to download this metadata to the visual project, my question is how to load said file or in which folder is stored, so that when the package is installed, it honors the translations that are checked.